# Drop down select ruby rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Here's my code for a form that contains a drop down list -

```
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :type, "Select profile type"%>
<%=
f.select :type, Profile::TYPES,
:prompt => "Select a profile type"
%>
</div>
```

The drop down menu looks fine. But, how would I check which option is selected? I want to route to a different view based on this selection.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You would check with javascript.

Answer (score 1):

The logic of routing to a different view should occur in your controller. When the user submits this form, check the value of the params, and perform your logic to route to a view:

```
class ExampleController

  def routing
    case params[:example][:type]
    when 'foo'
      redirect_to foo_path
    when 'bar'
      redirect_to bar_path
  end
end
```

You can create a custom action name, since this routing isn't one of the CRUD operations. You will need to place this route into the config/routes.rb file if it is a custom name.

Optionally, you can bind to the select's onChange event, as mentioned by others to auto-submit the form when the user changes the value. This would still send the data to the controller and perform a redirect. The advantage to this approach is that you can keep your route information out of Javascript, and in the Rail's controller.

More on Rails routing can be found here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
More on Javascript binding to onChange can be found here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp

Comment: I tried the first option by adding a custom action called "route" in my controller and also added the path in my routes.rb file. Now, I am getting this error -                                 "NoMethodError in ProfilesController#route

You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.[]"....Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use jQuery or any other popular Javascript framework to achieve this -- either attach an `onChange` listener or set the value somewhere and check it.  Events, yay, etc.